# How do I add multiple values to the 'data-attribute' and filter them with jQuery, based on some checkboxes?

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to filter results with multiple data attributes. Please look at the example code. When you select 'Memphis' OR 'Cardova' it should show 'Memphis and Cordova'. Currently this does not work. How should I approach this?

Below is my HTML:

```js
$('.filter').change(function() {
  //on each click, refresh visible / hidden for each item
  $('li.result').each(function(i, item) {
    var city = $(this).data('city');
    var visible = $('input.filter[data-city="' + city + '"]:checked').length > 0;
    visible ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
  });

  //if no checkboxes are checked, show everything
  if ($('input.filter:checked').length === 0) $('li.result').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input class="filter" data-city="Memphis" type="checkbox" /> memphis
  <input class="filter" data-city="Cordova" type="checkbox" /> cordova
  <input class="filter" data-city="Bartlett" type="checkbox" /> bartlett
</p>

<ul>
  <li class="result" data-city="Memphis,Cordova">Memphis and Cordova</li>
  <li class="result" data-city="Memphis">Memphis</li>
  <li class="result" data-city="Cordova">Cordova</li>
  <li class="result" data-city="Bartlett">Bartlett</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick:

```js
$('.filter').change(function() {
  //reset all classes (remove show class)
  $('li.result').removeClass('show');
  //loop over the filters
  $('.filter:checked').each(function() {
    //store the city of the filter in a string called 'city'
    var city = $(this).data('city');
    $('li.result').each(function() {
      //check if the data attribute of the result contains the city string
      //if it matches this filter, add the class 'show' to this result
      $('.result[data-city*="' + city + '"]').addClass('show');
    });
  });
  if ($('input.filter:checked').length === 0) {
    //if no checkboxes are checked, show everything
    $('li.result').show();
  }
  else {
    //else hide everything
    $('li.result').hide();
    //and show only items that match (with class 'show')
    $('li.result.show').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input class="filter" data-city="Memphis" type="checkbox" /> memphis
  <input class="filter" data-city="Cordova" type="checkbox" /> cordova
  <input class="filter" data-city="Bartlett" type="checkbox" /> bartlett
</p>
    
<ul>
  <li class="result" data-city="Memphis,Cordova">Memphis and Cordova</li>
  <li class="result" data-city="Memphis">Memphis</li>
  <li class="result" data-city="Cordova">Cordova</li>
  <li class="result" data-city="Bartlett">Bartlett</li>
</ul>
```